# How to fit my data to the container when the container has a transform applied to it

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG chart and the y-axis is created with negative pixel positions... This made me apply a transform and translate the chart over 35px to compensate for the negative positions. In doing so, it cuts off the last part of my data. How can I re-arrange this so that the data all fits in the container?

Ive tried separating out the y-axis labels to be in their own svg, and positioning it beside the main data svg with flexbox, but was still getting invisible overhang of data. Perhaps I didn't work out this fix far enough though?

```
<div class="total-chart-wrapper" id="total-chart-wrapper">
  <svg id="total-chart" height="285" width="100%">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="total-gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(76, 150, 254, 1.00)"/>
          <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="rgba(76, 150, 254, 0.70)"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.000)"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(40,40)">
    <g class="y axis" id="total-y-ticks">
      <line class="y-axis-zero-line axis-line" id="y-axis-zero-line-total" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="240"></line>
    </g>
      <g><polygon id="total-chart-polygon" fill="url('#total-gradient')"></polygon></g>
      <g class="x axis" id="total-x-ticks" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <line class="x-axis-zero-line axis-line" id="x-axis-zero-line-total" x1="0" y1="240" x2="600" y2="240"></line>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

It's too lengthy to put all of the code here, so here is a functional codepen: https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/eYYVEgW

If you inspect the data/polygon you can see its cutting off some data at the end.

Expected result is to fit all data into the svg. 
Actual result is invisible data overhang probably due to the transform applied over a g that encompasses the chart. I've been unable to fix this thus far due to the negative margins in the y labels to get them to the left of the chart origin. Any help?

Comment: Based on your code in the codepen is there a reason you cannot expand the parent div? If this is not acceptable I can take another look at it. Otherwise, it seems someone just suggested this below.

Comment: Yeah I need it to fit to all container widths (responsive width) so i just picked 600 since I know thats smaller than it needs to be.

Comment: So is the answer below satisfactory? Sorry it is unclear from your comment. Also is there a reason you are not using a javascript charting library like D3.js?

Comment: Answer below does not work and I'm not permitted to use a library unfortunately. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I have added a solution. See if that is conducive to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Javascript change the `const totalChartWidth` as below:

```
const totalChartWidth = document.getElementById('total-chart-wrapper').offsetWidth - 50;
```

The `- 50` will give you 50px on the left and fit your chart completely in the 600px parent div.

You can change this `- 50` to some code which dynamically calculates how much this spacer should be in order to make it more responsive.

Keep in mind though the way the code is setup, these values are obtained only on page load and therefore the chart won't be responsive on simple resizing of the window. It would need the page to be refreshed after resizing in order for you to see the effects.

```js
// Total bar container width 35 px
// Labels before formatting
const labels = [
  ['Wed', '11 PM'],
  ['Thu', '12 AM'],
  ['Thu', '1 AM'],
  ['Thu', '2 AM'],
  ['Thu', '3 AM'],
  ['Thu', '4 AM'],
  ['Thu', '5 AM'],
  ['Thu', '6 AM'],
  ['Thu', '7 AM'],
  ['Thu', '8 AM'],
  ['Thu', '9 AM'],
  ['Thu', '10 AM'],
  ['Thu', '11 AM'],
  ['Thu', '12 PM'],
  ['Thu', '1 PM'],
  ['Thu', '2 PM'],
  ['Thu', '3 PM'],
  ['Thu', '4 PM'],
  ['Thu', '5 PM'],
  ['Thu', '6 PM'],
  ['Thu', '7 PM'],
  ['Thu', '8 PM'],
  ['Thu', '9 PM'],
  ['Thu', '10 PM'],
  ['Thu', '11 PM'],
  ['Fri', '12 AM'],
  ['Fri', '1 AM'],
  ['Fri', '2 AM'],
  ['Fri', '3 AM'],
  ['Fri', '4 AM'],
  ['Fri', '5 AM'],
];

// Data points
const data = [
  0.25,
  0.56,
  0.5,
  0.5,
  0.86,
  0.45,
  0.3,
  0,
  0.3,
  0.6,
  0.4,
  0,
  0,
  0.8,
  0,
  0,
  0.4,
  0.3,
  0.1,
  0,
  0,
  0.2,
  0,
  0,
  0.4,
  0.7,
  0.1,
  0.6,
  0.4,
  0.6,
  0.4,
];

// Function to figure out max Y Tick
function yAxisRangeImperial(max) {
  if (max < 1) {
    return 1;
  } else if (max < 2) {
    return 2;
  } else if (max < 4) {
    return 4;
  } else if (max < 8) {
    return 8;
  } else if (max < 12) {
    return 12;
  } else if (max < 24) {
    return 24;
  } else if (max < 48) {
    return 48;
  } else if (max < 72) {
    return 72;
  } else if (max < 96) {
    return 96;
  } else {
    return 192;
  }
};

// Area chart

// Sum of all snowfall
const maxTotalValue = data.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0);
// Getting chart components by ID
const totalChart = document.getElementById('total-chart');
const totalXAxis = document.getElementById('total-x-ticks');
const totalYAxis = document.getElementById('total-y-ticks');
const totalPolygon = document.getElementById('total-chart-polygon');

const totalChartWidth = document.getElementById('total-chart-wrapper').offsetWidth - 50;

// Function to determine hour display interval
function hoursLabelTotalInterval(hours) {
  if (hours <= 6) {
    return 1;
  } else if (hours <= 12) {
    return 2;
  } else if (hours <= 24) {
    return 4;
  } else if (hours <= 36) {
    return 6;
  } else if (hours <= 48) {
    return 8;
  } else if (hours <= 60) {
    return 10;
  } else if (hours <= 72) {
    return 12;
  } else {
    return 24;
  }
}

// Function to create x axis labels
function createTotalLabels(labels) {
  const hoursInterval = hoursLabelTotalInterval(labels.length);
  let spacing = totalChartWidth/labels.length;
  let currentDay = '';
  const formattedLabels = labels.map((label, i) => {
      if (i % hoursInterval === 0) {
          if (label[0] !== currentDay) {
            currentDay = label[0];
              return [label[0], label[1]]
        }
          return ['', label[1]]
      }
      return ['','']
  });
  for (let i=0; i<formattedLabels.length; i++) {
    let translateDistance;
    if (i === 0) {
      translateDistance = 15;
    } else {
      translateDistance = i*spacing + 15;
    }
    if (formattedLabels[i][1].length && i !== 0) {
      totalXAxis.innerHTML += 
      '<g class="tick" transform="translate(' + translateDistance + ',0)"><line class="y-axis-zero-line axis-line dash gray" stroke-dasharray="4" stroke-width="1" x1="-13" y1="0" x2="-13" y2="240"></line><text class="label-day" dy=".71em" y="-20" x="0">' + formattedLabels[i][0] + '</text><text class="label-time" dy=".71em" y="-10" x="0">' + formattedLabels[i][1] + '</text></g>';
    } else {
      totalXAxis.innerHTML += 
      '<g class="tick" transform="translate(' + translateDistance + ',0)"><text class="label-day" dy=".71em" y="-20" x="0">' + formattedLabels[i][0] + '</text><text class="label-time" dy=".71em" y="-10" x="0">' + formattedLabels[i][1] + '</text></g>';
    }
  }
}

// Function to populate the y axis ticks and depth labels for total accumulation
function populateHourlyYAxisLabelsTotal(max, unit) {
  
  let maxYTick = yAxisRangeImperial(max);
  let tickContainer = document.getElementById('total-y-ticks');
  // Get x axis zero line
  let xAxisZeroLine = document.getElementById('x-axis-zero-line-total');
  
  let interval = maxYTick / 4;
  let ticks = [
    interval + unit,
    interval * 2 + unit,
    interval * 3 + unit,
    interval * 4 + unit,
  ];
  
  let width = totalChartWidth;
  let height = 240;
  
  tickContainer.innerHTML += '<line class="gray" x2="-30" y2="0"></line><line class="gray" x1="0" x2="' + width + '" y2="0"></line>';
  
  xAxisZeroLine.setAttribute("x2", width);
  
  for (let j=ticks.length-1; j>=0; j--) {
    if (j !== 0) {
      tickContainer.innerHTML += '<g class="tick" transform="translate(0,'+ (height - (60*j)) +')"><line class="gray" x2="-30" y2="0"></line><line class="gray" x1="0" x2="' + width + '" y2="0"></line><text class="y-tick" dy=".32em" x="-9" y="-30" style="text-anchor: end;">'+ ticks[j] +'</text></g>'
    } else {
      tickContainer.innerHTML += '<g class="tick" transform="translate(0,'+ height +')"><line x2="-30" y2="0"></line><text dy=".32em" x="-9" y="-30" style="text-anchor: end;">'+ ticks[j] +'</text></g>'
    }
  };
};

// Function to create area of accumulation
function accumulationAreaPoints(data, max) {
  let spacing = totalChartWidth/data.length;
  let maxYTick = yAxisRangeImperial(max);
  let summedDataSet = data.map(Number);
  summedDataSet = summedDataSet.map((elem, index) => summedDataSet.slice(0, index + 1).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
  summedDataSet = summedDataSet.map(function(each_element) {
    return Number(each_element.toFixed(2));
  });
  summedDataSet.unshift(0);
  for (let i=0; i<summedDataSet.length; i++) {
    let point = totalChart.createSVGPoint();
    let yLocation = (1 - summedDataSet[i]/maxYTick) * 240;
    point.x = spacing*i;
    point.y = yLocation;
    totalPolygon.points.appendItem(point);
  }
  let finalPoint = totalChart.createSVGPoint();
  finalPoint.x = summedDataSet.length*spacing - spacing;
  finalPoint.y = 240;
  totalPolygon.points.appendItem(finalPoint);
}

createTotalLabels(labels);
populateHourlyYAxisLabelsTotal(maxTotalValue, '"');
accumulationAreaPoints(data, maxTotalValue);

window.addEventListener('resize', populateHourlyYAxisLabelsTotal(maxTotalValue, '"'));
window.addEventListener('resize', accumulationAreaPoints(data, maxTotalValue));
```

```css
h1 {
  font: 24px sans-serif;
}
.bar {
  fill: #4a93ff;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}

.axis-line {
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.tick {
  opacity: 1;
}

.tick text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.tick line.gray, line.gray {
  stroke: #d9d9d9;
}
.label-day, .y-tick {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.label-time {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.total-chart-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="total-chart-wrapper" id="total-chart-wrapper">
  <svg id="total-chart" height="285" width="100%">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="total-gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(76, 150, 254, 1.00)"/>
          <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="rgba(76, 150, 254, 0.70)"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.000)"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g transform="translate(40,40)">
    <g class="y axis" id="total-y-ticks">
      <line class="y-axis-zero-line axis-line" id="y-axis-zero-line-total" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="240"></line>
    </g>
      <g><polygon id="total-chart-polygon" fill="url('#total-gradient')"></polygon></g>
      <g class="x axis" id="total-x-ticks" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <line class="x-axis-zero-line axis-line" id="x-axis-zero-line-total" x1="0" y1="240" x2="600" y2="240"></line>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: My goodness... that seems to have worked like a charm. Wow. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent div is set to 600 pixels.
Because of that, the parent is too small to fit the SVG.
By using transform you're also pushing the SVG further out of the wrapper.

```
.total-chart-wrapper {
    width: 600px;
}
```

change to:

```
.total-chart-wrapper {
    width: auto;
}
```

And it will work fine (it will pick the SVG width)